# Nested modals in nyromodal

Tags: php, nested, nyromodal

I'm using PHP & nyromodal to open a modal containing a series of images (called from the database). When one of these thumbnails is clicked, I want another modal to open (containing the larger image) on top of the already open modal. Instead, all it does is resize the already open modal and put the image in there. What I want is a new modal, so that when the user closes the new modal the old modal is still open underneath it...

Code:

One the main page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
$('a.projectmodaltrigger').nm();
$('a.projectcontentimgtrigger').nm();
});
</script>

<a href="project.php?id=1" class="projectmodaltrigger">
<img src="uploads/projects/1/test1.jpg" border="0" />
</a>
```

On the page that's opened in the modal (project.php):

```
<a href="uploads/projectcontent/1/image.jpg" class="projectcontentimgtrigger">
<img src="uploads/projectcontent/1/thumb/image.jpg" border="0" />
</a>
```

Is this possible? Sensible? Can anyone help?

Thanks,
HR

Comment: Can you post the snippet of code that you're using to open the modal? It's possible creates nested modals, so it needs to have a right code.

Comment: Thanks macgyver, I've edited my original post to include the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add target="_blank" in the first link:

```
<a href="project.php?id=1" class="projectmodaltrigger" target="_blank">
<img src="uploads/projects/1/test1.jpg" border="0" />
</a>
```

So nyroModal will open the target php page in an iframe and this should allow the nested modal as you need.
Let me know how it will go.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion macgyver. It didn't work for me (though it did fix one thing -- the jwplayer I put in the target now appears, it didn't appear before). But the target image now appears in the same window, only the window doesn't resize... I'm thinking of going with jqmodal actually, seems to have provision for nesting.

Comment: You are welcome. The resizing of a modal iframe window with nyroModal is another problem... it needs to deal with callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have solved this issue for myself, I can tell you what I did.

It is not enough to give the second modal the same class "projectcontentimgtrigger", you have to **explicitely ask nyroModal to stack the subsequent links** in modals like this :

```
$('a.projectmodaltrigger').nm({'stack' : true});
```

**Last thing :** if the second level modal must himself stack in a modal, you have to include the same call somewhere in your new page (e.g project.php for you). This could be solved with jquery.live() maybe (I did not try though). So again in "project.php":

```
$('a.projectmodaltrigger').nm({'stack' : true});
```

Hope this helps !